# AttributeError: 'SGD' object has no attribute 'get_updates' Mask_RCNN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation, mask-rcnn

I'm trying to start a training with Mask RCNN. First,I was having the same error like in https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/2243. It was regarding the scikit-image version. Once I implemented the patch from the discussion in the link above (changes in the utils.py) I started to have an error: AttributeError: 'SGD' object has no attribute 'get_updates'.

The only person which had the same error, fixed it somehow -> https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/2977

I use version of tensorflow 2.12.0 and can't switch to another one because I have a lot of other packages dependent on this particular version.

I'm also new to coding. If somebody knows how can I solve the problem, in which files to make changes and which changes to make, will apricuate a lot!

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.